# Specific ipython notebook won't load. Not sure what is wrong.

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am using mac os x. I have ipython version 1.1.0. Everything was working well. I finished up a project and ran it multiple times. Then, out of nowhere, I tried to open the project in ipython notebook and it won't open. I get a blank ipython notebook page with that is unresponsive, then after a few min I get a timeout error from google chrome that asks me if I want to kill the page.

I'm note sure how to better diagnose this error. [image: This is the only peice of evidence I was able to gather. It is the screen which does not load any further.]

Comment: Notebook might be too heavy, can you try on master that shoudl be slightly faster and/or share the notebook ? You can also try to strip the json from outputs, it will decrease notebook size.

Comment: Are errors getting thrown by iPython? Also try using the chrome's built in profiler.  Lastly was the notebook created in the same version of iPython notebook that you're trying to open it in?

Comment: I have the same problem.  The notebook is not very large, just has two cells of code and some output.  Also on OS X, with both Chrome and Safari.  No error messages from ipython.  Will try the profiler next time.